# Where can I find the Rails generator source for the -O option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to replicate the behavior of passing the `-O` option when generating a new Rails application. However, I can't find the source of this behavior. What do I need to do to replicate this behavior and/or find the source that determines this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That option is only used in one spot in the template for [config/application.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin/templates/rails/application.rb).  To replicate it yourself, add separate requires for each of the Rails components you want to application.rb:

Instead of this:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

Use this:

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

The same logic for the requires is used if you specify any of these flags: `--skip-active-record`, `--skip-test-unit`, or `--skip-sprockets`.

Comment: I don't think this is true...I just searched for `skip_active_record` and found [lots of places where it's referenced](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=✓&q=skip_active_record).